# VBA QueryTable and commented-out table

Tags: html, vba

I have a VBA routine that used QueryTable.Add very successfully to insert a table from a web page into my worksheet - last year.  I'm trying to import minor league baseball stats from (for example) the following page:  https://www.baseball-reference.com/register/team.cgi?id=5983843c

The routine below worked fine last year, but this year Baseball-Reference is rendering their page a little differently.  What is odd is that the team_batting table is normal html code and the team_pitching table is "commented out" with  tags.  It still displays in a browser, though - it looks like there is some code somewhere that extracts the team_pitching table from the comment and displays it.  You can see this behavior when you load the page - team_batting comes right up and there is a briefly-blank frame that is then filled with the team_pitching table.  The QueryTable command still works fine for the team_batting table, but ignores the team_pitching table.

This worked so beautifully for the past few years ... any idea on how to get around this problem?

Here's my code:

```
    InsertAt = ActiveCell.Address(False, False)
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & PgURL, Destination:=Range(InsertAt))
    .Name = "team"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
    .WebTables = """team_batting"""
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    .Delete
End With

Set FirstBlankCell = Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)
FirstBlankCell.Activate

InsertAt = ActiveCell.Address(False, False)

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & PgURL, Destination:=Range(InsertAt))
    .Name = "team"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = False
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
    .WebTables = """team_pitching"""
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    .Delete
End With
```

Comment: makes no sense what you are saying. i just recorded a query for that webpage and i was able to get any of the tables on that page.

Comment: thanks for looking at it, jsotola.  Can you show me your code for getting the team_pitching table?  If you view the source of this page and search for "team_pitching", you'll find four occurrences.  The fourth one is the id for the table.  You'll see that that table is in an html comment: < ! - -   and - - >.  The QueryTable above doesn't seem to "see" that table and doesn't retrieve it.

Comment: just create a `new query` in the `data` tab, and have the macro recorder running while doing it. .... you will have to do it every time the webpage changes its format.

Comment: That's a great idea, jstola, but it didn't work for me.  When I try and "Get External Data From the Web", the page selection window only offers me a single yellow-box arrow to select the entire page.  There are no yellow-box arrows for the individual tables (which seems really odd - after you suggested this, I remembered that I'd done this before.)  Even if I import the entire page, though, it still only imports the team_batting table.

Comment: you are not reading what i wrote `new query`, not `Get External Data From the Web`

Comment: I read "new query" but didn't know what you meant by that - I didn't see that option on the data tab.  I see now that you assumed I was using the same version of Excel that you are.  I do see that option on another computer with a newer version of Excel and the query did work (not exactly as I wanted, but I'll work on that), so thank you for your help jstola.

Answer (score 0):

since you are not able to record the query because of the excel version, here is a recording (prettyprinted)

```
Sub Macro1()

    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Team Pitching", _
        Formula:="let" & vbCrLf _
               & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://www.baseball-reference.com/register/team.cgi?id=5983843c""))," & vbCrLf _
               & "    Data3 = Source{3}[Data]," & vbCrLf _
               & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(" _
               & "                          Data3,{" _
               & "                                  {""Rk"",   Int64.Type }, {""Name"",  type text  }, " _
               & "                                  {""Age"",  Int64.Type }, {""W"",     Int64.Type }, " _
               & "                                  {""L"",    Int64.Type }, {""W-L%"",  type number}, " _
               & "                                  {""ERA"",  type number}, {""G"",     Int64.Type }, " _
               & "                                  {""GS"",   Int64.Type }, {""GF"",    Int64.Type }, " _
               & "                                  {""CG"",   Int64.Type }, {""SHO"",   Int64.Type }, " _
               & "                                  {""SV"",   Int64.Type }, {""IP"",    type number}, " _
               & "                                  {""H"",    Int64.Type }, {""R"",     Int64.Type }, " _
               & "                                  {""ER"",   Int64.Type }, {""HR"",    Int64.Type }, " _
               & "                                  {""BB"",   Int64.Type }, {""IBB"",   Int64.Type }, " _
               & "                                  {""SO"",   Int64.Type }, {""HBP"",   Int64.Type }, " _
               & "                                  {""BK"",   Int64.Type }, {""WP"",    Int64.Type }, " _
               & "                                  {""BF"",   Int64.Type }, {""WHIP"",  type number}, " _
               & "                                  {""H9"",   type number}, {""HR9"",   type number}, " _
               & "                                  {""BB9"",  type number}, {""SO9"",   type number}, " _
               & "                                  {""SO/W"", type number}, {""Notes"", type text  }  " _
               & "                                })" & vbCrLf _
               & "in" & vbCrLf _
               & "    #""Changed Type"""

    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet           ' put data in new worsheet

    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add( _
            SourceType:=0, _
            Source:="OLEDB;" _
                  & "Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;" _
                  & "Data Source=$Workbook$;" _
                  & "Location=""Team Pitching""", _
            Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable

        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Team Pitching]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = False
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Team_Pitching"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, jstola.  I was actually able to record the query on my work computer (which has a newer version of Excel), though I haven't had a chance to work through it yet.  I will compare what I captured against your version.  Thanks again - I appreciate your help.